# Isometric map drawing, generating

Tags: java, graphics, geometry

I am making an isometric game and I only managed to create a zigzag isometric map. My original idea was diamond shape but I cant manage to do so.

Diamond:
coobird.net/img/tile-diamond-good-order.png

Zigzag:
coobird.net/img/tile-zigzag-compact.png

Here is a bit of my code to show you what is happening:

World:

```
  public void chunkGenerate() {
    moduleX = ((ListManager.getTileWidth()*8));
    moduleY = ((ListManager.getTileHeight()*8));
    for (int x = 0; x <= width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <= height; y++) {
            if ((x%moduleX) == 0) {
                if ((y%moduleY) == 0) {
                    chunkList.add(new Chunk(x,y));
                }
            }
        }
    }
          }
```

Chunk:

```
 public void Generate() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0;y< 8; y++) {
            tileList.add(new Tile(location.getX()+(x*ListManager.getTileWidth()),location.getY()+(y*ListManager.getTileHeight()),0));
        }
    } 
}
```

Rendering:

```
        for (Chunk c : w.getChunkList()) {
            g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (int i = 0; i<c.getTileList().size(); i+=2) {
                g2d.drawImage(test2, (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getX()+c.getTileList().get(i).getOffset().getxOffset()), (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getY()+c.getTileList().get(i).getOffset().getyOffset()+w.getvOffset()), this);
                g2d.drawImage(test2, (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getX()), (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getY()+w.getvOffset()), this);
            }
            for (int i = 1;i<c.getTileList().size(); i+=2) {
                g2d.drawImage(test2, (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getX()), (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getY()+w.getvOffset()), this);
                g2d.drawImage(test2, (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getX()+c.getTileList().get(i).getOffset().getxOffset()), (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getY()+c.getTileList().get(i).getOffset().getyOffset()+w.getvOffset()), this);

            }
        }
```

I need help with making the map into a diamond, instead of zigzag. If you need further information on the code, comment below. Also one bug with this code is that there is like a 1 pixel wide space every couple of tiles. I don't know why.. I tried adjusting the offsets, didn't help..
Current offsets: (Tile constructor)

```
 offset = new IsometricOffset(21,11);
```

Closest I got to having no space was 20,10 but there was still a tiny space

here is a pic:

http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/6242/picbz.png

Thanks for the help!
edit:
Apparently two of the tiles on the screen are actually only 1 tile in the engine. I am working on fixing it.

EDIT:

Changed and got this:
img526.imageshack.us/img526/3121/test333.png

drawing:

```
        for (Chunk c : w.getChunkList()) {
            /*for (int i = 0; i<c.getTileList().size(); i++) {
                g2d.drawImage(test2, (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getX()), (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getY()+w.getvOffset()), this);
            }*/
            for (int i = 0;i<c.getTileList().size(); i++) {
                g2d.drawImage(test2, (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getX()+c.getTileList().get(i).getOffset().getxOffset()), (c.getTileList().get(i).getLocation().getY()+c.getTileList().get(i).getOffset().getyOffset()+w.getvOffset()), this);

            }
        }
```

(I tried drawing without the offsets it drew the same thing as the picture)
Generating:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0;y< 8; y++) {
            tileList.add(new Tile(location.getX()+(x*ListManager.getTileWidth()/2),location.getY()+(y*ListManager.getTileHeight()/2),0));
        }
        location.setX(location.getX()+ListManager.getTileWidth()/2);
        location.setY(location.getY()+ListManager.getTileHeight()/2);
    }
```

After experimenting:

Generate:

```
        public void Generate() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0;y< 8; ++y) {
            tileList.add(new Tile(location.getX()+(y*ListManager.getTileWidth()/2),location.getY()-(y*ListManager.getTileHeight()/2),0));
        }
        location.setX(location.getX()+ListManager.getTileHeight()/2);
        location.setY(location.getY()+ListManager.getTileWidth()/2);
    } 
}
```

result: This is the closest i got:
http://img814.imageshack.us/img814/3450/bombombom.png

Comment: Tell me if you need more information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to imagine your map rotated by 45 degree.

```
              (0, 3)
       (0, 2)        (1, 2)
(0, 1)        (1, 1)        (2, 2)
       (1, 0)        (2, 1)
              (2, 0)
```

And the rendering cycle must be like that:

```
x = 0, y = 100,
for (dx = 0; dx < 3; ++dx) {
    for (dy = 0; dy < 3; ++dy) {
        drawTile(x + dy * width / 2, y - dy * height / 2);
    }
    x += width / 2;
    y += height / 2;
}
```

**UPD: Proof of working.**

Code (actionscript, but there is no difference for algorithm):

```
var x:Number = 100, y:Number = 100, 
    dx:Number, dy:Number, px:Number, py:Number,
    halfWidth:Number = 40, halfHeight:Number = 20,
    s:Sprite = new Sprite(),
    g:Graphics = s.graphics;

g.lineStyle(1, 0xffffff);
for (dx = 0; dx < 3; ++dx) {
    for (dy = 0; dy < 3; ++dy) {
        px = x + dy * halfWidth;
        py = y - dy * halfHeight;

        g.moveTo(px - halfWidth , py);
        g.lineTo(px, py - halfHeight);
        g.lineTo(px + halfWidth, py);
        g.lineTo(px, py + halfHeight);
        g.lineTo(px - halfWidth, py);
    }
    x += halfWidth;
    y += halfHeight;
}

addChild(s);
```

Result:

[image: good looking tiles]

Comment: It helped but i got this: 
http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/3121/test333.png

Here is some of my code that I changed:

posted in the thread

Comment: Try to change first argument of drawTile, like I edited.

Comment: http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/9945/asddsd.png - Result

Comment: Still cant figure it out

Comment: check your code, i made calculations in excel, and all is right.

Comment: I made it work its now diamond but the tiles are half on top of each other how do i fix that?

http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1158/tesfx.png

Comment: dont devide width on 2 in x coord

Comment: So close!! 
This is what I got when i didn't divide width by 2:
http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/1641/tttb.png

Comment: Looks like you do not have aspect of tile width:height as 1:2, just try to use second argument like `y - dy * height/width` or so. Experiment with this.

Comment: Tried it this is as close as I manage to get
http://img814.imageshack.us/img814/3450/bombombom.png

Comment: I just need them to make diamonds once that is done ill figure out how to generate them together...

Comment: I am not sure how to fix it I did experimenting cant figure it out

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong I have tested yours independently and it doesn't work.

Comment: Just check your code. My algorithm is working fine, i tested it on flash, look updates.

Comment: solved it, Thanks for the help!

Comment: I did it in a different way from online because I have tried this and it didn't work.